# Struggling with looping a list or array of datagridviewrows,How can i loop a datagridviewrow list?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

[heres an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qATqh.png) Im getting a "System.NullReferenceException,System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null." error when i try to access the value of a certain cell in an array , basically what im trying to do is create 2 arrays of rows and then pass the datagridview3 rows to them ,if the checkboxes are checked or not,then 
loop these arrays to send data to a database.Edit:It shows that arrays index is -1

```
        DataGridViewRow[] x = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView3.Rows.Count];
        DataGridViewRow[] y = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView3.Rows.Count];


            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView3.Rows[row].Cells[onayver.Index].Value) == true)
            {

                x[row] = dataGridView3.Rows[row];


            }
            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView3.Rows[row].Cells[reddettt.Index].Value) == true)
            {
                red.Add(dataGridView3.Rows[row]);
            }

        }
        MessageBox.Show(x.Count().ToString());

        for (int r = 0; r < x.Count(); r++)
        {
            infos.randevuisim = x[r].Cells[nameofistek.Index].Value.ToString(); //the error is right here
            infos.randevuzaman = x[r].Cells[timeofistek.Index].Value.ToString();
            infos.randevukulid = Convert.ToInt32(x[r].Cells[kullaniciofistek.Index].Value.ToString());


            Operations.IstekOnayla(infos.randevuisim, infos.randevuzaman, infos.randevukulid);


            Operations.KullaniciIstekGoster(dataGridView3);
            dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns();

        }
```

Comment: It is much, much easier and cleaner to do this using DataViews.  One view can be set to show where boolval is true, the other where it is false.  The rows "move" with no code needed from you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)